# Conversion between types in discriminated unions

Tags: f#, type-conversion, discriminated-union

I have a function, which can returns different types, and I use *discriminated union* for this. What I need, is to have conversion from one type in discriminated union to another type. 
Also some of the types can be convertable to all other types (*String*), but some of the types can be converted only to String (*MyCustomType*)

For this I've added member method *ConvertTo* to the `ResultType`:

```
type MyTypes = 
   | Boolean       = 1
   | Integer       = 2
   | Decimal       = 3
   | Double        = 4
   | String        = 5
   | MyCustomType  = 6

type ResultType = 
   | Boolean of bool
   | Integer of int
   | Decimal of decimal
   | Double of double
   | String of string
   | MyCustomType of MyCustomType

   with 
     member this.ConvertTo(newType: MyTypes) = 
       match this with 
       | ResultType.Boolean(value) -> 
           match newType with 
           | MyTypes.Boolean -> 
              this
           | MyTypes.Integer -> 
              ResultType.Integer(if value then 1 else 0)
          ...
       | ResultType.MyCustomType(value) -> 
           match newType with 
           | MyTypes.MyCustomType -> 
              this
           | MyTypes.String -> 
              ResultType.String(value.ToString()) 
           | _ -> 
              failwithf "Conversion from MyCustomType to %s is not supported" (newType.ToString())
```

I don't like such construction, because if I add more types, this requires me to do many changes: *MyTypes*, *ResultType* and also in several places in the *ConvertTo* member function.

**Can anybody suggest better solution for such types conversion?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you add more types, the matrix of conversions is O(N^2), so of course there are a lot of changes, it is intrinsically a large problem.

Comment: @Brian. I'm not sure is this can be used here and how to implement in right way, but is it possible to use some intermediate type *MyIntermediateClass* for conversion, and Convert to other types like: *Double -> MyIntermediateClass -> MyCustomClass* - in this case it will be O(2*N).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With a slightly different design, it is possible to exploit `System.Convert.ChangeType` and the fact that the constructors of discriminated unions are actually functions:

```
// statically typed wrapper for System.Convert.ChangeType
let conv a : 'T = System.Convert.ChangeType(a, typeof<'T>) :?> 'T

type MyCustomType() = class end

type ResultType = 
  | Boolean of bool
  | Integer of int
  | Decimal of decimal
  | Double of double
  | String of string
  | MyCustomType of MyCustomType
  with
    member this.ConvertTo (newType:'T->ResultType) =
      match this with
      | Boolean b -> newType( conv b )
      | Integer i -> newType( conv i )
      | Decimal d -> newType( conv d )
      | Double d -> newType( conv d )
      | String s -> newType( conv s )
      | MyCustomType m ->
         if typeof<'T> <> typeof<string> then
            raise (new System.InvalidCastException("MyCustomType can only be converted to String"))
         else
            String (m.ToString())

let i = Integer 42

let b = i.ConvertTo Boolean
printfn "%A" b

let d = i.ConvertTo Decimal
printfn "%A" d

let d2 = i.ConvertTo Double
printfn "%A" d2

let s = i.ConvertTo String
printfn "%A" s

//let mi = i.ConvertTo MyCustomType  // throws InvalidCastException

let m = MyCustomType (new MyCustomType())
let sm = m.ConvertTo String
printfn "%A" sm

//let im = m.ConvertTo Integer // throws InvalidCastException
```

EDIT: Once you add more custom types, this will not help much.

Maybe you should make your custom types implement `IConvertible`. Then you can remove the special case code from `ConvertTo` and completely rely on `System.Convert.ChangeType`.

You would still have to extend every custom type's `ToObject` implementation whenever you add a new custom type. Whether that really is better than a central `ConvertTo`function is debatable.

Comment: Thank you, this is simplest and more clear code than I have. It also fix my mistake, when I add one more enumeration type. Override *IConvertible* interface will help with conversion to CLR types (but I use only few of them - other will be redundant). Also open question about usage one big *ConvertTo* function or add several *ToObject* implementation to custom types

Answer (score 2):

Why are you wanting to do type conversion to begin with?  Discriminated Unions are a good way of hiding type information until you need it and abstract complexity away.  Generally you have a match statement in a function that consumes this type and then you only cast if you need to.

If you're trying to make some type of parser or language engine then you have no choice but to define all the cast or at least their error states.  If you wouldn't mind elaborating on why / what you would use this for, maybe I could suggest another approach.

An aside: F# and .NET in general doesn't support overloading of return types.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Yes this is used by parser, which has comparable big syntax tree. The result of each function depends on result (and result type) of the childs (return type can be different for different childs - dependent on inner operation). Some elements in AST requires conversion to other type. I was thinking about some unified function, but it will be very big, if I use 30 custom classes for example. This is why I asked about suggestion - possible somebody knows about some special algorithm, some other approach for this

Comment: Possible as the solution, will be expand types in discriminated union and add personal *ConvertTo* method to each type. For example: change **| Boolean of bool** to **| Boolean of BooleanType** and add *ConvertTo* to the new *BooleanType* type

Comment: I'm not sure how that would help.  If you really need `this.ConvertTo` then you're forced to bite the bullet.  Id use sub functions and the wild card operator _ to increase readability.  Trying to get rid of `this.ConvertTo` may just force all this logic into the rest of your code and will most likely lead to code duplication.